# I can not figure out why I can not start this simlple python script

Tags: python, pycharm

My directory looks like this

[image]

When I start directly with PyCharm it works.
But when I try to start the script with a commandline I get this error messsage

```
 > python .\PossibilitiesPlotter.py

    Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\SwapMatrixPlotter\possibilitiesplotter\PossibilitiesPlotter.py", line 7, in <module>
from plotterresources.PlotterProps import PlotterProps
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotterresources'
```

This is how the import looks from my main class PossibilitesPlotter.py

```
import sys

sys.path.append("plotterresources/PlotterProps.py")

from csv import reader
from pathlib import Path

from plotterresources.PlotterProps import PlotterProps
from possibilitiesplotter.PossibilitiesGraph import PossibilitiesGraph
from possibilitiesplotter.PossibilitiesModel import PossibilitiesModel

class PossibilitiesPlotter:
```

Comment: `Possibilitiesplotter` is inside the folder `possibilitiesplotter`, and the module you are trying to import is a sibling folder, not a child folder.

Comment: This is about PATH definitions. PyCharm probably adds "SwapMatrixPlotter" to your PythonPath. This module setup looks like it **urgently** needs a good module structure, take a look at [this doc](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/) for more information.

Comment: How can I fix this? Can I not write an import like in Java? Without add something to the path?

Comment: You should **never** explicitly add something to your PATH variable from within a module. Even from within a calling script this is not a good idea in general, but may be acceptable depending on the case.

Comment: You don't have any `__init__.py` files

Comment: I have already tried to include in the packages empty __init__.py file. Did not help

Answer (score 0):

As a **workaround**, add the following line to `PossibilitesPlotter.py`:

```
sys.path.append("../plotterresources/PlotterProps.py")
```

This will add the directory one level above the **commandline pwd** to the PATH variable. So this is **always relative** to the location of the **calling script/shell**.

**Thus in general:**

**NEVER** append to the PATH/PYTHONPATH variable from within modules. Instead **restructure your module**. For more details, take a look at the documentation on [*Packaging Python Projects*](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/)